# font-weight gets inherited in unordered list

Tags: css

I have a problem with font-weight: bold getting inherited to nested links within that list item.

I only want those links within a li element that has the "selected" class to be bold.

http://jsfiddle.net/lasseedsvik/aDQfL/

HTML:

```
<ul class="submenu">
<li class="submenu-root-node selected">
    <a href="/first">first</a>
    <ul class="submenu-submenu-container">
        <li class="submenu-sub-item">
            <a href="/second">second</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="submenu-root-node">
        <a href="/third">third</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.submenu a
{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.submenu li.selected a
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.submenu-sub-item a {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

I prefer only having to do this in the css, since the unordered list is generated server-side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/aDQfL/2/

```
.submenu a
{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

 li.selected > a
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: remove this class ".submenu-sub-item a"